# Change texture of ImageButton on click LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I would like to change the texture of my ImageButton on button click but after several attempts, it still doesnt work.

Intended Results:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALCjU.png -> [before click][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxw1Y.png -> [after click]

This is how i declare my ImageButton:

```
    notSelected = new Texture("buttons/btn_difficulty_notselected.png");
    selected = new Texture("buttons/btn_difficulty_selected.png");
    image = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(notSelected));
    image1 = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(selected));
    this.btnEasy = new ImageButton(image);
    this.btnEasy.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            pressed = 2;
            handleInput();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The image can be changed automatically for you if you assign a style. It's unclear from your question whether it's the background or the jewel image that you want to change when the button is pressed, but you can handle both with a style. `up` is the default drawable used for the button background, and the optional `down` is the drawable for when it's pressed. And there's `imageUp` and `imageDown` for the icon.

```
ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle();
style.up = image;
style.down = image1;
btnEasy = new ImageButton(style);
```

Comment: I just tried this but I want it to be image1 even after touch up background should remain as image 1 until i click on another button then it goes back to image

Comment: Do you need to be able to click it when it is in this other state with image1?

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve it with:
        ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup(btnEasy, btnMedium, btnHard);
        buttonGroup.setMaxCheckCount(1);
        buttonGroup.setMinCheckCount(0);
        buttonGroup.setUncheckLast(true);